# Is there a bound of percentage/number of influential points for a given size sample?

Tags: multiple-regression, references, linear-model, residuals, cooks-distance

Consider for a given data set of size $N$, and we do a linear regression analysis on it. We know that we can define *influential points* among this dataset by setting a threshold value on the *Cook's distance* of each point defined as

$$D_{i}=\frac{\left(\hat{\beta}-\hat{\beta}_{(i)}\right)^\prime\mathbf{X^\prime X}\left(\hat{\beta}-\hat{\beta}_{(i)}\right)}{p\cdot \textrm{MSE}}$$

where $p$ is the number of regressors in the model being analysed.
We define a data point $x_{i}$ to be an influential point if $D_{i}\geq \alpha$.

My question is that: although it is certainly not possible that all $N$ points are all influential points, is there a bound for number/percentage of influential points? Say, is there any result claiming that "There cannot be more than $0.5N$ influential points whatever the dataset is."

Or is there any related geometric interpret of Cook's distance on a specific statistical manifold embedded suitably?

**Note**: I have looked through [Cook&Weisberg,1982] for the motivation of Cook's distance, it arises in the cases that there are few influential points among a large amount of "tame points". So if there is no such bound for the number of influential points, then Cook's distance is not very solid in some pathological situations since it is against intuition that there are more "influential points" in a dataset than "tamed points" ("tamed points are those which are not influential among the dataset").

Comment: What's a "tammed point"? I don't think I recall this term.

Comment: @Glen_b Those which are not influential, "tammed" is just a fancy word to distinguish, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah, I think I see -- did you mean "tamed"?

Comment: @Glen_b oh,yes...sorry for the typo:)

Comment: Edited for clarity. I'd probably have said "non-influential" myself.